# Multiline text in svg

Tags: svg

I know how to draw text line in a rectangle:

```html
<svg width="200" height="100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="white"/>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>    
</svg>
```

Now I would like the text to break. It should look roughly like this:

```
line.....
   TEXT
line.....
```

I tried to use `<br>` in the text, but this did not work.

This should be rendered in modern browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, ...)

The result should look like this:

[image: line1-text-line2-in-box]

Comment: It appears you want to render two separate lines with the text between them. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @daShier I added a image of the desired result. Is it easy to understand now? If not, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multi-line recording, it’s convenient to use [tspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan)

In svg there is only absolute positioning. 
The `x` and `y` coordinates determine the position of the first character of the text`

`<tspan>` tag helps shorten tag entry `<text>`

Otherwise, I would have to write for each line of text the full form of writing the tag `<text>`

```html
<svg width="40%" height="40%" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="white"/>
  <text  fonnt-size="48"   > 
     <tspan x="4em" y="1.5em">line1 ...</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" >TEXT</tspan>
    <tspan x="4em" y="4.5em">line2 ...</tspan>
   </text>    
</svg>
```

**Update**

If you need to position multitext using CSS rules inside the SVG then use [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)

```html
<svg width='200' height='100' style="border:1divx solid gray; ">
     
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="none"/>
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100">
       <style>
          .container 
    {
          width: 200px;
    font-size:20px;
    }
         .line
   {
       padding:0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 3em;
         }
          .text
    {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
       </style>
       <body xmlns="httdiv://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <div class="container">
              <div class="line">line1 .....</div>
              <div class="text"> TEXT</div> 
              <div class="line">line2 .....</div>
           </div>
        </body>   
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well one major limitation in the .SVG standard is the lack of multi-line text. There's no way to specify a "new line" in .SVG. You either need to make two `<text>` fields or use the `<tspan>` element. Unfortunately, even with ` you need to roll your own, but it would look something like:

```html
<svg width="200" height="100">

<text x="100" y="25" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
   <tspan x="50" dy=".6em">Line1...</tspan>
   <tspan x="50" dy="1.2em">TEXT</tspan>
   <tspan x="50" dy="1.2em">Line2...</tspan>
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't break text automatically or by using BR tag in SVG. You need to define x, y or dx, dy for each text/tspan node.

#### Though here is a hack:

You can create a path and assign that path to the text as given in code snippet.

You can create 1 path for all text or you can create many paths for many text lines as in your case you need to create 3 paths.

Though this is not a proper solution and need to modify each time you want to make changes in your text/position. Still this is an alternate way.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <path id="my_path" d="M 20,20 l 80 0 M 50 70 l 90 0 M 20 120 l 80 0" stoke-width="10px" stroke="transparent" />
  
  <text font-size="30px">
<textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#my_path">
  line..... TEXT line.....
</textPath>
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The path ("M 20,20 l 80...") looks like binary to me. I am new to svg. How do you get to these values? With an application, guessing, black magic?

Comment: No, its just moveTo & lineTo like you can use your pen in a plain paper, M 20,20 Move your pen to 20, 20 to X and Y without drawing anything then  l 80 0 draws a line from that 20, 20 to 80 and 0 X and Y. Again repeat the same step for moveTo and lineTo. I hope it helps, for more please visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths